# Not able to migrate defaultcollection from tfs 2010 to tfs 2012

Tags: tfs-migration

I am trying to migrate projects from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012. I am following the steps given below:

- Detach Team Project Collection
- Back up the collection database and restore it in target machine.

Some of the projects are in DefaultCollection project. When I try to attach the collection in Team Foundation server, I do not get the option to restore DefaultCollection. I am not able to connect to this collection from visual studio. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Have I missed any step during the migration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the Application Tier on the target server using Team Foundation Server Administration Console?

If that install/configuration left you with an empty DefaultCollection already there, you need to either delete that or rename your original collection to avoid naming collision.